# Can't find my images under resources manager when trying to add a ImageView in Android Studio

Tags: image, android-studio, imageview

[image]

I have 6 jpg images in my drawable folder (all underlined red, how do I view the reason for the errors?) but when I open my resource manager while adding a ImageView in design view, none of the six images can be found. How do I add images to my android app?

Comment: I just downloaded random cat images that are also jpgs and they worked. I can't get my original six images to work though. What's causing the red error underlines to appear? If I could know the error I could fix this.

Comment: You named your image wrongly. You cannot set the image name to start with a number. You entered the name of the image as `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` which is the wrong naming convention. Change 1.jpg to some text name that starts with some text or letter like `img1.jpg`. You can see red line under all image. Let me know after implementing this